# Не работает инкремент в bash

Tags: bash

Добрый вечер. Разбираюсь с башем. Задание: Дан текстовый файл, содержащий имена файлов в текущем каталоге. Посчитать количество файлов, которые реально существуют и являются регулярными файлами. Считаю, но инкремент не работает, хотя слово "Haha" исправно выводится столько раз, сколько файлов в каталоге. Прошу помощи, уже перепробовал разные инкременты из разных статей, присваивания - толку 0. Переменная i всегда равна нулю

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
cat files | while read line
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; i=$(( $i+1 )) 
    fi
done
echo $i
```

Вот так проблема решена:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; i=$(( $i+1 ))
    fi
done <files
echo $i;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому-что `while` после `|` это другой процесс, используйте for (в простейшем случае) или возвращайте счетчик через stderr (есть способ и напечатать и вернуть через stderr)

вот так как-то

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n' 
for line in $(cat files)
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; ((i++)) 
    fi
done
IFS=old_IFS;
echo $i
```

можно еще так:

```
while read line
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; ((i++)) 
    fi
done <files
```

или, если надо вывод от команды

```
while read line
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; ((i++)) 
    fi
done < <(cat files)
```

Comment: К сожалению ни один из примеров не работает на Ubuntu 11.04:
1 - всегда ноль
2 - Haha
f: 5: i++: not found
Haha
f: 5: i++: not found
Haha
f: 5: i++: not found
3 - Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Работает так: #!/bin/bash
i=0
while read line
do
    if [ -e $line -a -f $line ]; then echo "Haha"; i=$(( $i+1 ))
    fi
done <files
echo $i; Спасибо большое за идею!

Comment: ((i++)) не работает ? странно это довольно старая конструкция. 

    $ i=0;((i++));echo $i
    1

bash 4.2.37 debian.